# Performance optimisations using Span<T>

Tags: c#, performance, .net-5

For parsing astronomical datasets (mostly images) I have written a parser that reads .fits files in C# .net5.0.

The content part of the file basically constists of a blob (byte array) that holds all the datapoints in a certain order.

What this parser does is read in all those values from the content part. However, since the datatype can be either `byte`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `float`, `double` the data has to be parsed accordingly.

So, here is the code:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FitsLibrary.DocumentParts;
using FitsLibrary.Extensions;

namespace FitsLibrary.Deserialization
{
    public class ContentDeserializer : IContentDeserializer
    {
        private const int ChunkSize = 2880;

        public Task<Memory<object>?> DeserializeAsync(PipeReader dataStream, Header header)
        {
            if (header.NumberOfAxisInMainContent == 0)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<Memory<object>?>(null);
            }

            var numberOfBytesPerValue = Math.Abs((int)header.DataContentType / 8);
            var numberOfAxis = header.NumberOfAxisInMainContent;
            var axisSizes = Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfAxis)
                .Select(axisIndex => Convert.ToUInt64(header[$"NAXIS{axisIndex}"])).ToArray();
            var axisSizesSpan = new ReadOnlySpan<ulong>(axisSizes);
            var totalNumberOfValues = axisSizes.Aggregate((ulong)1, (x, y) => x * y);
            Memory<object> dataPointsMemory = new object[totalNumberOfValues];
            var dataPoints = dataPointsMemory.Span;
            var contentSizeInBytes = numberOfBytesPerValue * Convert.ToInt32(totalNumberOfValues);
            var totalContentSizeInBytes = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(contentSizeInBytes) / Convert.ToDouble(ChunkSize)) * ChunkSize;
            var contentDataType = header.DataContentType;
            Span<byte> currentValueBuffer = stackalloc byte[numberOfBytesPerValue];

            var bytesRead = 0;
            var currentValueIndex = 0;
            while (bytesRead < contentSizeInBytes)
            {
                var chunk = ReadContentDataStream(dataStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var blockSize = Math.Min(ChunkSize, contentSizeInBytes - bytesRead);
                bytesRead += blockSize;

                for (var i = 0; i < blockSize; i += numberOfBytesPerValue)
                {
                    chunk.Buffer.Slice(i, numberOfBytesPerValue).CopyTo(currentValueBuffer);

                    dataPoints[currentValueIndex++] = ParseValue(contentDataType, currentValueBuffer);
                }

                dataStream.AdvanceTo(chunk.Buffer.GetPosition(blockSize), chunk.Buffer.End);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<Memory<object>?>(dataPointsMemory);
        }

        private static object ParseValue(DataContentType dataContentType, ReadOnlySpan<byte> currentValueBytes)
        {
            return dataContentType switch
            {
                DataContentType.DOUBLE => BinaryPrimitives.ReadDoubleBigEndian(currentValueBytes),
                DataContentType.FLOAT => BinaryPrimitives.ReadSingleBigEndian(currentValueBytes),
                DataContentType.BYTE => currentValueBytes[0],
                DataContentType.SHORT => BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(currentValueBytes),
                DataContentType.INTEGER => BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(currentValueBytes),
                DataContentType.LONG => BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(currentValueBytes) as object,
                _ => throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid data type"),
            };
        }

        private static async Task<ReadResult> ReadContentDataStream(PipeReader dataStream)
        {
            return await dataStream.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I also wrote some benchmarks for the code:

```
|                  Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |     Median |     Gen 0 |     Gen 1 | Gen 2 |  Allocated |
|------------------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|-----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|-----------:|
|  WithEmptyContentStream |  1.452 ms |  2.209 ms |  2.949 ms |  0.0068 ms |         - |         - |     - |      488 B |
|         With10IntValues |  3.422 ms |  5.172 ms |  6.905 ms |  0.0354 ms |         - |         - |     - |     1456 B |
| With1MillionFloatValues | 79.357 ms | 13.250 ms | 17.688 ms | 70.2609 ms | 4000.0000 | 1000.0000 |     - | 34849504 B |
```

The benchmarks can be found here: https://github.com/RononDex/FitsLibrary/blob/development/FitsLibrary.Tests/Benchmarking/ContentDeserializerBenchmarks.cs

As you can see, the test with 1 Million Float Values (= 4Mb of data) ends up allocating almost 35Mb of data.

Is there any way the above code could be optimised further?

Comment: There's something useful for you in the [upcoming .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/) like [Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/).

Comment: thanks, that actually looks awesome

Comment: Why don't you `await` the `ReadContentDataStream` call?

Answer (score 4):

In general, the optimization problems are supposed to be solved using a profiler, which is more effective than the people looking at the code for the first time. In this case I'd also add that before starting to optimize we would want to ask ourselves if the problem is really there. There are very few situations when a supposedly rare operation consuming 35Mb of memory would be a problem.
As for the code,

- You are stating that its purpose is to read files. So how did they end up in a pipe?
- Your function is supposedly async, only it's not. And I don't see a good reason why not, your pipe interface is async, sprinkling async/await as needed should not be too difficult. Or if it is not needed, it'd be better to drop the Tasks
- The return value is weird. I have trouble understanding how a Memory can be conveniently used in the calling code when it does not even know the data type. And since it is still an array, returning Memory gives you nothing, unless the calling code requires it of course.
- The types are there for a reason. By using an array of objects effectively circumventing the type system, you not only make the life of the calling code difficult, you are increasing the memory usage and decrease the performance, since the values need to be boxed to fit into the array of objects.
- Why are you checking the type for each value? It is not going to change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time. To answer your questions: The document consists of different parts, header, content an extension headers. All of them are made up of chunks of 2880 bytes length. Usually the bigest part of the document is the content (like a 20MP photo for example). So the content parser is by far the most important part performance wise.

Yes I am aware of the async await part, however, other parsers for different document parts can correctly make use of it and its part of the interface, which is why this is marked as async

Comment: 3. The returned data from the parser is not directly accesable to the caller. There are generic helper functions for dealing with this

Comment: 4. That actually sounds like a good idea (not having to check for datatype for every data value). However, I don't see a way how I could just check once, there would still be some kind of if logic somewhere?

Comment: The idea is that since the caller will need to have separate processing for different datatypes anyway, you could create a generic function Deserialize<T> which can work with Memory<T> and in doing so both avoid the boxing overhead and make the code safer and easier to comprehend.

Comment: I already tried using generics, the problem is there is no generic to parse byte streams into the generic type (`BinaryPrimitives` does not support generics). However, you gave me an idea on how to have the `switch` statement only run once, and not for each data type, I might try that.

Comment: @RononDex, maybe I did not state it my answer clearly: without the profiler data, my best guess for the reason of the memory consumption would be boxing. It is of course a guess, since profiling it in my mind is quite difficult. But if it is the case, you are not going to fix it until you get rid of your object[].